# How does it rain in Foreign countries, like the Amazon rain forest, than in India, when no one there performs yajnas for the Devas?

Tags: gods

The scriptures say that yajnas please the devas, and the devas being pleased, shower rain:

> The demigods, being pleased by sacrifices, will also please you; thus nourishing one another, there will reign general prosperity for all.

If so, how does it rain more in Foreign countries, like the Amazon rain forest, than in India, when no one there performs yajnas for the Devas?

Does this falsify the claim that Yajnas produce rain as its reward?

Answer (score 3):

First of all, to God no one is outsider, as He is the Father and Mother of all:

> Gita 9.17 Of this world I am the father, mother, ordainer, (and the), grand-father; I am the knowable, the sancitifier, the syllable Om as also Rk, Sama and Yajus.
>
> Gita 9.23 Even those who, being devoted to other deities and endowed with faith, worship (them), they also, O son of Kunti, worship Me alone (though) following the improper method.
>
> Gita 9.24 I indeed am the enjoyer as also the Lord of all sacrifices(Yajnas) ; but they do not know Me in reality. Therefore they return to the world.

Yes, "from yajna, clouds are created',

> Gita 3.14 From food are born the creatures; the origin of food is from rainfall; rainfall originates from sacrifice; sacrifice has action as its origin.

But yajna does not mean those of India alone:

> Gita 4.11 According to the manner in which they approach Me, I favour them in that very manner. O son of Partha, human beings follow My path in every way.
>
> Gita 9.23 Even those who, being devoted to other deities and endowed with faith, worship (them), they also, O son of Kunti, worship Me alone (though) following the improper method.

So God deprives none.

Comment: But the thing is, the rain is rewarded to the country where the yajnas are performed, not to everyone.

Comment: @Ikshvaku in all countries there are good people and there are bad people.Good people are engaged in some form of Yajna in every country. I think that is the spirit.

Comment: So yajña here doesn't necessarily mean fire sacrifice...that's a good interpretation for the 21st century. But you need to find a commentary that says yajña need not involve fire.

Comment: @sv. It is well known that Yajna does not always mean "fire sacrifice." There is something called the "Pancha maha yajna," and Vedadhyayanam is called the "Brahma yajna" or sacrifice to Brahman. This is said in the Vedas and is not merely a 21st century interpretation.

Comment: @Ikshvaku "It is well known that Yajna does not always mean fire sacrifice." - the answerer still needs to make that connection citing either a commentary, a verse from Vedas or an alternate meaning of yajña from the dictionary.

Comment: @sv. Please take a look: https://www.wisdomlib.org/hinduism/book/manusmriti-with-the-commentary-of-medhatithi/d/doc200118.html